# When should I convert a loop over collection to Linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, resharper

I recently starter using ReSharper.

ReSharper suggests to convert all your loops over collections (usually `foreach`) to a `Linq` statement, even if the loop contains various conditioning.

- Does this improve performance?
- Does this make code more readable?

In general, when should I follow ReSharper suggestion in this matter, and when I should not?

Comment: This is too vague to give a concrete answer to. Do *you* think the code is more readable afterwards? Always, or just sometimes?

Comment: @Jon, sometimes I find it more readable. but most of the times (usually when lots conditions are involved) it makes it much less readable, IMHO.

Comment: It's obvious when the conversion makes it more readable *to me* - but deciding if it makes it more readable to other folks is a bit harder... you have to have a good idea of your target audience. In this respect, the choice is *extremely* subjective IHMO - but a choice that nevertheless still has to be made!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this improve performance?

In general it does not affect performance. It is possible to engineer situations where using LINQ either improves *or* degrades performance, but not in the general case.

> Does this make code more readable?

A lot of times yes, because it replaces a construct that emphasizes the *mechanics* of the iteration with one that emphasizes the *purpose* of the iteration.

Emphasis on mechanics:

```
var jacks = new List<Person>();
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    if (person.Name == "Jack")
    {
        jacks.Add(person);
    }
}
```

> "This code iterates over persons, and every time it finds a person named Jack it adds them
>   to the list named jacks".

Emphasis on purpose:

```
var jacks = persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack").ToList();
```

> "Take all persons whose name is Jack and put them into a list. We 'll call that list jacks."

It also doesn't hurt that the second version is much shorter, so your brain can consume it all at once much more readily than the first.

Another example:

```
var furryAnimals = furryThings.Intersect(animals).ToArray();
```

There is absolutely no way you are going to be able to match the clarity of this without LINQ or writing your own equivalent. Here it is immediately clear that `furryAnimals` contains anything that is both in `furryThings` and in `animals`. That's all you care about.

You *don't* care about exactly how the intersection of these sets is calculated. The calculation might involve a dictionary as an implementation detail. But an alternative version of the code that starts with creating that dictionary immediately draws your attention to the one thing that is least important: the implementation detail.

> In general, when should I follow ReSharper suggestion in this matter,
>   and when I should not?

There are always exceptions to the rule, so I won't try to present one here. But in general we want code to be correct, maintainable and fast (usually in that order). I am going to assume that the code is correct either way, so whenever you have to make a decision, always consider:

- does the change make the code clearer to understand? does it make the code easier to modify in the future?

If you have **concrete proof** that the speed of the code is critical, also consider:

- which version runs faster?

Comment: This is wrong: "In general it does not affect performance". In most cases, LINQ slightly decreases performance and increases memory traffic (bad thing). This is the cost of readability.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy: I 'm not too sure about that. Can you expand a bit?

Comment: LINQ uses lambdas (anonymous delegates). Delegate invocation is a little bit slow, delegate creation is even more slow, and aftewards delegate must be garbage collected. Of course, this doesn't matter unless you use LINQ thousand times in a loop.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy: Now I get your point. Mine is that LINQ does not induce a perf penalty just by appearing at the scene, for example `data.Any()` or `data.OrderBy(d => d.Id)` -- in the first case there is no delegate, and in the second most ways to sort like that would also work by accepting a comparison delegate. This is what I had in mind when saying "in the general case". But you are also right in that `Select` is a very common operation and it does result in indirection through a delegate.

Comment: `Select` could be cached. `Where` is the most dangerous, because conditions often captures variables in a closure, forcing .NET to create and garbage collect complex classes for lamdbas.

Comment: The performance difference between using Linq vs classical implementation, is so marginal, that it falls under micro-optimizations. Even then, rewriting a few key LINQs is enough. The saying that LINQ improves performance comes from a law, that if it's more readable, it's easier to get right. The greatest source of performance bottlenecks is bad code, that invites hacks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is personal.

LINQ does not automatically make your code faster. The opposite is more likely to be true. Take a look at: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx

LINQ can make your code shorter.

LINQ can make your code more readable. But Sometimes LINQ can also have very complex combinations and then I choose for the "old" ways.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper does not take into account readability of code, converted to LINQ. So, it can generate quite complex expressions that are harder to understand then the classical loops.

Converting to LINQ code, by itself, does not change the performance, so it is more of the code-style preference.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ makes code more readable, but in most cases readability comes with a performance cost. The reason is that lamdbas (anonymous delegates) are classes that must be allocated in memory and garbage collected afterwards. Well, CLR tries to be clever and caches delegates when it is possible, but that is not enough, unfortunately. Besides, lamdba invocation is a little bit slower than a simple method call.

That is why ReSharper can do both: convert code to LINQ and convert LINQ to code. When you care about readability, convert everything to LINQ. When you care about performance, set low inspection priority for converting to LINQ and instead convert LINQ to code when you see it. Usually I write code first as LINQ, and then use ReSharper to convert it to code. Really saves time.